# Need to take a screenshot headless

Tags: python-3, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I have a weather station and take a screenshot of a webpage (windy.com) once an hour to integrate into my display which runs on a Pi 3

It was working perfectly until I had an SD card crash and had to rebuild it - I stupidly didn't have a backup of the SD card I now have Pi OS Bullseye, Python 3.9.2 and Selenium 4.1.3 This is the old program that was working on PI OS Buster with Python 3.7 and Selenium 1.9ish

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from PIL import Image
import pygame
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)
url = "https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=53.514&lon=-2.944&detailLat=53.393&detailLon=-2.134&width=530&height=490&zoom=4&level=surface&overlay=wind&product=ecmwf&menu=&message=true&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=true&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=mph&metricTemp=%C2%B0C&radarRange=-1"
driver.get(url)
driver.fullscreen_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.set_window_size(530,445)
driver.save_screenshot('weather.png')
basewidth = 530
img = Image.open('weather.png')
driver.quit()
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('/home/pi/images/weather_icons/kia.bmp')}
```

It will not work with the new Pi Bullseye, Python3.9 and Selenium 2.4 I had so many errors and gradually got rid of them all but now I'm left with this error and I cannot figure out how to fix it

**This is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/map.py", line 6, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-v7 unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5
```

This is the modified code I had to use to get this far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from PIL import Image
path = ('/usr/lib/chromium-browser')
s = Service('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-v7')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability("goog:loggingPrefs", {'performance': 'ALL'})
url = "https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=53.514&lon=-2.944&detailLat=53.393&detailLon=-2.134&width=530&height=490&zoom=4&level=surface&overlay=wind&product=ecmwf&menu=&message=true&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=true&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=mph&metricTemp=%C2%B0C&radarRange=-1"
driver.get(url)
driver.fullscreen_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.set_window_size(530,445)
driver.save_screenshot('weather.png')
basewidth = 530
img = Image.open('weather.png')
driver.quit()
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('/home/pi/images/weather_icons/kia.png')
```

My chromium-chromedriver is the latest version (98.0.4758) and my chromium browser is Version 98.0.4758.106

Can anyone tell me how to get this working without having to go back to the old versions of everything?

This is what it looks like *when it works* it's currently showing a screenshot of the map from a week ago
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Nobody have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I currently have the same problem with chromedriver on a raspberry pi. Firefox-esr seems to work with selenium, but not chrome. Not doing headless, but remote development with vscode which seems to make it think it is headless